# how to overlay text on webrtc RTCVideoView flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-webrtc

I want to overlay the text on RTCVideoView flutter and also record this text along with the video.

I'm using Flutter Webrtc package for video rendering and I want to overlay text on the screen and save it after that.

Comment: I do not know Flutter Webrtc, but generally, if you want to overlay stuff the Stack Widget allows you to do that.

Comment: But I want to record that text as well and in this scenario, the stack widget will not help.